# Stair-stepping when converting from Cartesian to Here.com tiles

Tags: here-api, directx-9, cartesian-coordinates, proj

I'm trying to stitch together tiles onto a Windows directX 9 screen.  My problem is that the tiles are stair-stepped on the screen.  I think this is because on my Cartesian coordinate system has the same Y given the same latitude independent of X (or longitude).

My app uses the Proj4 APIs to convert to/from lat/lng and a user-chosen coordinate system (e.g., NAD83, Zone Connecticut) which is Model X/Y cartesian.  I'm using the slippy C# code (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#C.23) to convert to/from lat/lng and tiles.  So, I convert as follows View-> Model X/Y -> lat/lng -> Tile X/Y -> lat/lng -> Model X/Y -> View.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?  Changing my coordinate system for my view rendering is not an option because customers import DXF files that are using those Cartesian coordinate systems.

Answer (score 0):

I made the incorrect assumption that my screen projection was perfect lat/lng tiles.   A straight horizontal line on a state-mapped projection does not maintain the same latitude whereas the tiles do. When rendering my texture, I just had to make sure all corners were converted to my Model coordinates, thus stretching the image to the upper right and lower left slightly.